# Correlation between 2 columns after doing percentage change between consecutive rows for both columns

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, exploratory-data-analysis

I am checking whether two columns in my pandas dataframe are correlated, but then wondering if it makes a difference if I do percentage change first (using pandas pct_change().mul(100) function) to both columns then use corr()

Does it matter if I find correlation using the raw numbers instead of the percentages difference between consecutive rows?

My overall goal is to be able to check if change in both columns have an association before proceeding to determine best way to put the association in a regression equation

Comment: Why not try it and see?  Use a data frame with a tiny number of rows--three would be ideal.

Comment: I used these two as columns in my dataframe. [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
  [2, 1, 4, 5, 8, 12, 18, 25, 96, 48]. Before applying pct_change().mul(100) on the dataframe there was correlation of 0.76, but after there applying correlation dropped to -0.01